# How to show a popup floating panel window when a MenuBarExtra button clicked or hotkey pressed?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am writing a macOS application, which only shows in the menu bar. When user clicked a button on the menu bar or pressed some hotkey, it will show a [floating panel](https://cindori.com/developer/floating-panel). But I don't know how to showing it because there's no other view to embed in.

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct uCopyApp: App {
    @State var showingPanel = false
    var body: some Scene {
//        WindowGroup {
//            ContentView()
//        }
        MenuBarExtra("MenuBar", systemImage: "line.diagonal") {
            Button("Show a window") {
                // how to show a popup window?
            }
            Button("Quit") {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `FloatingPanel.swift`:

```
class FloatingPanel<Content: View>: NSPanel {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    init(view: () -> Content,
         contentRect: NSRect,
         backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType = .buffered,
         defer flag: Bool = false,
         isPresented: Binding<Bool>
    ) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        super.init(contentRect: contentRect,
                   styleMask: [.nonactivatingPanel, .titled, .resizable, .closable, .fullSizeContentView],
                   backing: backing,
                   defer: flag)
        isFloatingPanel = true
        level = .floating
        collectionBehavior.insert(.fullScreenAuxiliary)
        titleVisibility = .hidden
        titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        hidesOnDeactivate = true
        standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
        animationBehavior = .utilityWindow
        contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: view().ignoresSafeArea().environment(\.floatingPanel, self))
    }
    override func resignMain() {
        super.resignMain()
        close()
    }
     
    override func close() {
        super.close()
        isPresented = false
    }
     
    override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
        return true
    }
     
    override var canBecomeMain: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

private struct FloatingPanelKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: NSPanel? = nil
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var floatingPanel: NSPanel? {
        get { self[FloatingPanelKey.self] }
        set { self[FloatingPanelKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

I know how to open a window by using [openWindow API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/openwindow). But the FloatingPanel is a subclass of NSPanel, so I don't know how to handle it in SwiftUI.

Comment: Would it work to use the `.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)` modifier on your MenuBarExtra to just show your content as a popover instead of a floating panel? Or do you somehow _need_ a floating panel? Alternately, you could create an old-style `NSStatusItem` and trigger showing your panel from there.